# How to optimise this IN query?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-performance, index-tuning

Lets say I have this schema

```
Resource(resource_mapping_id:Uuid,
reaource_id: uuid,
node_id: varchar,
date: date,
available: boolean,
resource_start: varchar,
resource_end: varchar)
```

So i have the composite key formed on `(resource_mapping_id, resource_id, node_id, date, resource_start, resource_end)`

Note: the node is is also uuid stored as text.
Now I have these 2 queries:

`update resource set available = :value where resource_id=:somevalue and date=:somedate and resource_start=:sometime and resource_end=:sometime`

And

`select * from resource where resource_id In (:resourceidlist) and date in (:dates) and node_id in (:nodeIds)`

This table contains huge number of records, you can say around 500 million or so..

So whenever I hit these queries via my Java application through jpa, they made the CPU utilisation of the database spiked up to 100%.

So after doing analysis, I created an index say

`Index(resource_id, node_id, date)`

Which in turn fixed the issue with the update query, even when it runs in parallel threads, the CPU never spiked up even a bit.

But now coming to the select statement, i was having issues when the parameters went high.
So i batched them, i mean in a batch x no. of node ids, resource ids and dates can be processed, even though, with 100(note, size of all parameters is same, if i tel 100, all total its 300) parameters, it spiked up the cpu and the other threads go into a waiting state!

How to resolve this issue? Should I change my query or something? Ot should I make any other change or create further index only for this situation based? Please help me.

I am using postgres v13.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: Thank you, surely I will follow it. Most probably I will edit this post tomorrow morning as its late night here and I don’t have my laptop with me.

Answer (score 1):

To support that `SELECT` statement, you first need to figure out which of the three conditions are selective, that is, filter out a substantial number of rows. For each selective condition, create a B-tree index on only that column, so that you end up with up to three single-column indexes.

PostgreSQL can combine these indexes to speed up the query. A multi-column index is not very useful in this case.

For the `UPDATE`, a multi-column index on all columns that appear in the `WHERE` clause would be perfect. But PostgreSQL can also make use of single-column indexes like the ones we created above.

There is always a tradeoff: indexes can speed up queries, but they slow down data modifications. So you don't want to have too many of them.

Comment: So you're telling, i should create 3 single column index and try them in both the queries?

Comment: Yes, but only create them for those columns where the condition promises to be selective.

Comment: note: resource id, date and node id all can be repetitive, only resource_mapping_id is unique in this table 

So is that a good idea? And this should work well for both of the queries, right?

Comment: It should work for both queries. A column does not have to be unique for the condition to be selective.

Comment: Hey, I tried with the above indexes you mentioned, I deleted the multi column index and created 3 separate indexes on 1, resource_id, 2, date and 3. node_id, it works great for update query but not for the select query with multiple in queries.

Comment: Then there is nothing you can do to speed up that query. You may want to edit your question and add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for your slow query.

Answer (score 0):

Create Table Index in where clause sequence and try it.
Eg.

```
where resource_id In (:resourceidlist) and date in (:dates) and
node_id in (:nodeIds)
```

Table index like

```
Table Index(resource_id, date , node_id )
```

Comment: I tried it, same issue, doesn't give any performance benifit.

Comment: note: resource id, date and node id all can be repetitive, only resource_mapping_id is unique in this table